# how to set endpoint address using nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

How do you set endpoint address currently I have the following endpoint address:

What I need is:

The third party application that is connecting to my service generates an error saying service not found:

Failure in initializing Port Type (11754)

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000032500

So I'm assuming its because endpoint isn't ?wsdl

How do you do this using nusoap?

tried :

```
$server->wsdl->endpoint = "Http://www.example.com.server.php?wsdl";
```

But didnt work.

Any ideas?

Comment: $server->configureWSDL("text", "test",$endpoint,"document");

Comment: this fixed it but still get error